# Smart Home Device showing small cog and no commands

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I have a node.js script in AWS Lambda which is connected to my Project via API Gateway.

I've got the actions-on-google library included OK and my devices get discovered.  However, depending on what I select as the device type, affects whether in Google Home the device shows with a little cog on the icon (and no commands available).

The below works absolutely fine and I can see the device and commands available:

```
app.onSync(async (body, headers) => {
  return {
    requestId: body.requestId,
    payload: {
      agentUserId: '123', 
      devices: [{
        id: 'washer-123',
        type: 'action.devices.types.OUTLET',
        traits: [
          'action.devices.traits.OnOff',
          'action.devices.traits.StartStop',
          'action.devices.traits.RunCycle'
        ],
        name: {
          defaultNames: ['My Washer'],
          name: 'Washer',
          nicknames: ['Washer']
        },
        deviceInfo: {
          manufacturer: 'Acme Co',
          model: 'acme-washer',
          hwVersion: '1.0',
          swVersion: '1.0.1'
        },
        attributes: {
          pausable: true
        }
     }]
   },
 }
});
```

However, exactly the same but with the type changed to `Door` fails and all I can see in Google Home is the app settings:

```
app.onSync(async (body, headers) => {
  return {
    requestId: body.requestId,
    payload: {
      agentUserId: '123', 
      devices: [{
        id: 'washer-123',
        type: 'action.devices.types.DOOR',
        traits: [
          'action.devices.traits.OnOff',
          'action.devices.traits.StartStop',
          'action.devices.traits.RunCycle'
        ],
        name: {
          defaultNames: ['My Washer'],
          name: 'Washer',
          nicknames: ['Washer']
        },
        deviceInfo: {
          manufacturer: 'Acme Co',
          model: 'acme-washer',
          hwVersion: '1.0',
          swVersion: '1.0.1'
        },
        attributes: {
          pausable: true
        }
     }]
   },
 }
});
```

Is there anything specific about the `DOOR` device type compared to the `OUTLET` type that might be causing this to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Touch controls](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls#supported_device_types) are supported for `OUTLET`, but not for `DOOR`.